# How to use InteractiveViewer to pan across a Table or Column that's larger than the viewport

Tags: flutter, dart

Developing a game that involves a large grid that is going to be larger than the viewport. All cells in the grid are the same height/width (square).

Since it's a grid, I cannot use SingleChildScrollView to pan in both directions. I can use two of them to achieve both x and y scrolling, but not at the same time.

Based on what I've seen, it appears that the new InteractiveViewer could handle this. However, it does not seem to pan outside of the viewport.

Below is some minimal sample code. This is using Table/TableRow/TableCell, but I have seen the same issue with Column/Row/Container.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget()
        
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<TableRow> getChildren() {
  
  List<TableRow> children = List<TableRow>();
  
  for( var x = 0; x < 20; x++ ) {
    List<TableCell> colChildren = List<TableCell>();
    
    for( var y = 0; y < 20; y++ )
    {
      colChildren.add(
        TableCell( child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Center( child: Text(x.toString()+","+y.toString()))
        ))
      );
    }
    children.add(
      TableRow( children: colChildren)
    );
    
  }
  return children;
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      child: Table (
        children: getChildren()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this page which helped me solve the issue: https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/constrained.html

Basically, if the child is larger than the viewport, you need to add the constrained:false property to the InteractiveViewer, and then it'll work!

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      constrained: false,
      child: Table (
        children: getChildren()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is InteractiveViewer will instantly scale to maxScale value and you lose scaling interactions. If constrained is set back to true (default value), then scaling will work properly but then again you cannot pan Table to outside of the viewport.